# The pointer passed in as a String must not be in the bottom 64K of the process's address space

Tags: c++-cli

I have a string object which is passed between managed (C++/cli) and unmanaged (C++) environments.

```
    const WCHAR *unique() const { return L"Hellow World" ; }
    String^ csCol = gcnew String(unique());
    String^ csColOut = csCol;
```

Now I want to do append "__a" to csCol which I do as:

```
     csCol = csCol + "__a"
```

However it seems to be giving an error: "The pointer passed in as a String must not be in the bottom 64K of the process's address space". Can someone please help me understand as to where am I going wrong.

Comment: Most programmers call that a NullReferenceException.  That happens, it isn't clear how "uniqu" got a value from the snippet.

Comment: @HansPassant Unique's value is non null. Its a part of larger code, therefore did not write it

Comment: @HansPassant How can I append another string to csCol? I know the resize method in C++ works for increasing the size of the string. But how do I increase the size of String^

Comment: How is `uniqu` allocated?

Comment: @Swordfish  I have edited the code to include that

Comment: Allocate memory on the heap.

Comment: @Swordfish Ok how to?

Comment: Since I don't know anything about your application, i can't possibly know. I assume `unique()` is a C++ function inside a dll that gets loaded by a `C++/cli`-application?